# Ajuda agrupamento em consulta SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá, pessoal!

Estou tentando agrupar os resultados dessa busca da seguinte forma:

| Dia | Resultados |
| --- | --- |
| 10/01/22 | 4 |
| 11/01/22 | 5 |
| 12/01/22 | 6 |

Tentei utilizar o `Group By`, mas não deu muito certo.
Tentei utilizar tanto o `sum()`, quanto o `count()`, mas acho que utilizei de maneira incorreta.
Alguem pode me ajudar a  organizar esse resultado?

```sql
SELECT count(*) "Quantidade", 
       tabela.data "Dia" 
 FROM tabela
WHERE idDoEvento = 14 
 AND idDoUsuario IN (SELECT id 
                     FROM usuariosEGrupos 
                     WHERE groupoid = (
                            SELECT id 
                               FROM usuariosEGrupos 
                               WHERE nome = 'GrupoPadrao'
                           )
                       )
AND TRUNC(tabela.data) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('12/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY tabela.data 
ORDER BY tabela.data ASC;
```

O resultado está da seguinte  forma:
|Quantidade|Dia|
|---|--------|
|1| 10/01/22|
|1| 10/01/22|
|1| 10/01/22|
|1| 10/01/22|
|1| 11/01/22|
|1| 11/01/22|
|1| 11/01/22|
|1| 11/01/22|
|1| 11/01/22|
|1| 12/01/22|
|1| 12/01/22|
|1| 12/01/22|
|1| 12/01/22|
|1| 12/01/22|
|1| 12/01/22|

Comment: Você já tentou colocar o ORDER BY TO_DATE(tabela.data, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  pra vê o que retorna?

Comment: Olá, amigo. Obrigado pelo retorno. Ao executar inserindo essa alteração no order by, o retorno é o mesmo.

Comment: E fazendo o TRUNC(tabela.data) ? ORDER BY TRUNC(tabela.data) ?

Comment: Também o mesmo resultado...

Comment: voce ja tentou colocar o count, depois do dia no select?

Comment: Na verdade no GROUP BY TO_DATE(tabela.data, 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: Já tentei sim. Sobre o groyp by, retorna o seguinte erro ORA: ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY.

Comment: Olá, adventistaam! Obrigado pela sua ajuda. Consegui resolver essa questão.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, amigo.
A coluna que armazena a data, é formatada em *'DD/MM/YYYY'*, ou possui mais campos como *'HH:MM:SS'*?
Pode ser que a estrutura de sua consulta esteja correta, entretanto ele está agrupando as datas levando em conta as unidades de hora, minuto, etc.
Ex.:
A data:
*11/02/2016 12:10:45*
não seria agrupada com:
*11/02/2016 21:05:12*.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Olá, Vitor. Obrigado pelo retorno. Na coluna que armazena a data, contém apenas o informativo de dia, mês e  ano no formato descrito.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada na sua consulta então.

Comment: A única coisa que eu consigo imaginar que poderia resolver seria colocar um TRUNC. Ex.: SELECT ... TRUNC(tabela.data) "Dia" e GROUP BY TRUNC(tabela.data).

Comment: Tenta fazer a consulta sem os WHERE, só para ver se continua "bugando".

Comment: Utilizando trunc no select ele acaba retornando a mesma coisa. Sobre o group by, é retornado o erro ORA: ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY.

Comment: Tem que ser os dois juntos

Comment: Vitor, muito obrigado! Utilizei o trunc em todos os lugares onde tinha "tabela.data" e funcionou!

Comment: Fico muito feliz que funcionou!